# UITableView Separator Style Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview that is blank by default.  User can add cells to it.

I want the separator lines to be clear when there are no cells, and grey when there are cells.

I am using this code:

```
if ([[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count] == 0)
{
    self.routineTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    self.routineTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
else
{
    self.routineTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}
```

The problem is, when I launch the app with a blank table, and if I add cells, the grey lines are not there there until I restart the app.  But if I start with cells there, then delete them, then re-add them, the lines are there.   Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is this code being called? Does it get called before a cell is added?

Comment: it is being called in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Which case is hit when you launch the app with a blank table?

Comment: `if ([[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count] == 0)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe you are missing this?

```
...
else
{
    self.routineTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine; // or you have the previous 'None' style...
    self.routineTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}
```

---

**EDIT** :
You need this but not only this... According to Apple Documentation :

> The value of this property is one of the separator-style constants described in `UITableViewCell` Class Reference class reference. `UITableView` uses this property to set the separator style on the cell returned from the delegate in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

That means the style wont change for cells that are already loaded. Just scrolling the table to force cells to redraw should make separators appearing...

You then have to :

1. set it BEFORE cell is inserted

   OR
2. reload `tableView` when the first cell is added

which is not easy to do with a `NSFetchedResultsController`, you should look into its [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate) for a solution... or change direction, like hiding the `tableView` until you have a result maybe...

---

**EDIT 2** : You can also simply add this :

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

but that's a dirty workaround that will just reload full tableView, losing most benefits of `NSFetchedResultsController`...

Comment: edited my answer with explanation... and a dirty workaround that should work :)

Comment: unfortunatey `[self.routineTableView reloadData];` did not work eitherl

Comment: have you have set `separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine`? in which method is your code?

Comment: I have added that, as you suggested.  Maybe I can just hide the tableview if fetch is nil?  do you know how to do that?

Comment: that would be anyway the best solution imho to hide the separator, you could just use self.routineTableView.hidden = YES; or add a blank UIView over it...

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix I usually do is:

```
#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorStyle:)]) {
        [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This changes the boolean flag of whether there will be a separator or not. Put this in viewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

And to make sure you've really made it go away, set the seperatorColor property to whatever the background color of the view and cell would be:

```
// If the background is white
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

So then even if somehow the above does not get called and the separator is still persisting - it would be the same color as what is behind it, therefore invisible.

Good luck.