# Separator of UITableViewCell does not hidden in iOS5

Tags: uitableview, ios5, separator

in TableView Controller, viewWillAppear, it is set as:

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Everything works just fine in iOS4.x, but in iOS5, the separator still appear! And more strange, that line just change the height for every different cell, normal size, tiny size and even disappear, while dragging up and down for the table view.~!? The behaviors are unpredictable...

Anyone encounter this case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233445/uitableview-separator-style-question Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

**Just uncheck TableView Property > Separator to None from Xcode,then Clean And Build your project..  its Works!!!... Sometime it does not work by code in iOS5**