# Xamarin ListView separators randomly appearing

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, separator

I'm using Xamarin forms PCL and deploying on android.

I have a listview that when has no results displays the string *"Nothing to show"* as a unique item of the list.

When this is done I also deactivate the items separation line because if I don't I have a silver grey line under the unique item.

Then, when  I have results I reactivate the items separation line.

BUT ! When reactivating the line not all items have it !

For instance it can look like this :

item1
------------
item2

item3
-----------
item4
----------
item5

item6

As you can see there is no separator between item 2-3 and 5-6 for no reason at all.

All elements are added in a for loop. They are all strings.
The bug is random and can be between any items.

To show the separators I do :

```
myList.SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.Default;
```

And to hide them :

```
myList.SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None;
```

Is this a bug on my end or from Xamarin forms ?
Any idears of how to fix this ?

Comment: Is this on an emulator? I've had this happen on an emulator before because the resolution was too small

Comment: @cvanbeek Nope this is on an actual phone !

Comment: I allways choose to set the SeparatorVisibility to None and create my own separator with a BoxView inside the DataTemplate.

Comment: Is this on the emulator or an actual device?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set ListView's IsVisible property to false when items.Count() == 0 and set a Label "No items found" IsVisible property to true when items.Count() == 0

Answer (score 0):

This property is not meant to be set dynamically. As you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6233491/202179, those changes on iOS are rendered only when cell is rendered again, which means that you would have to use `ReloadData` on the native table to make it consistent. As that method is not exposed in the `ListView` there is no way out of the box to do what you ask for.